# WPF Draggable Panel Class

Tags: wpf, canvas, center, drag

I'm trying to write a panel class from this two resources:

- [WPF: how to make the (0,0) in center inside a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871358/wpf-how-to-make-the-0-0-in-center-inside-a-canvas)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx

The panel class will have two attached properties "X" and "Y" and if any element gives x and y to be zero then it will be placed on the center of the Panel. The panel will also let the user to drag things around . Please help me write this class. I'm very new to WPF.

---

This is how far I've come. Now I tried to implement this but its not working, if you can help me implement the GetTop,GetLeft,GetBottom,GetRight functions which are not by default defined in panel class and which are neccessary. If these 4 methods are present then dragging functions can be implemented here.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SmartERP.Elements
{
    public class SmartCanvas : Panel
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TopProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BottomProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RightProperty;

        static SmartCanvas()
        {
            TopProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Top", typeof(double), typeof(SmartCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
            LeftProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Left", typeof(double), typeof(SmartCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
            BottomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Bottom", typeof(double), typeof(SmartCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
            RightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Right", typeof(double), typeof(SmartCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
        }

        public double Top
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(TopProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(TopProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Bottom
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(BottomProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(BottomProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Left
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(LeftProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(LeftProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Right
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(RightProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(RightProperty, value); }
        }

       private double GetTop(UIElement element)
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(TopProperty);
        }

        private double GetLeft(UIElement element)
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(LeftProperty);
        }

        private double GetBottom(UIElement element)
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(BottomProperty);
        }

        private double GetRight(UIElement element)
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(RightProperty);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            Point middle = new Point(arrangeSize.Width / 2, arrangeSize.Height / 2);

            foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
            {
                if (element == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                double x = 0.0;
                double y = 0.0;
                double left = GetLeft(element);
                if (!double.IsNaN(left))
                {
                    x = left;
                }

                double top = GetTop(element);
                if (!double.IsNaN(top))
                {
                    y = top;
                }

                element.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(middle.X + x, middle.Y + y), element.DesiredSize));
            }
            return arrangeSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: How can I implement this. Please help.

Comment: Soham, you did not explain what you are attempting to implement.  How can any of us answer a question when we don't know what the question is?  What are you trying to accomplish?  What does your code currently do or not do?  How does it deviate from the expected behavior?  How is your custom panel used (with example code)?  Explain these things and someone here can probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to write a custom panel which will position its elements in the dead center if its top and left property are set to be 0,0. The child element center should be at 0,0 not the child top corner. Also I'm trying to achieve dragable behavior based on this resource - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx.

Comment: What purpose do your dependency properties Top, Left, Bottom and Right serve?

Answer (score 1):

> The panel class will have two attached properties "X" and "Y" [...]

OK, then you should implement those attached properties. See the example in Section **Custom Attached Properties** of the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) on MSDN. Here's how this would look for `X`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("X", typeof(double),
        typeof(SmartCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));

public static void SetX(UIElement element, double value) { element.SetValue(XProperty, value); }
public static double GetX(UIElement element) { return (double)element.GetValue(XProperty); }
```

Once you have done this, you have `GetX` and `GetY`, which is probably what you mean by `GetTop` and `GetLeft`.

Comment: Now please I'm using the RegisterAttached but I'm still not able to drag things around the canvas and not place any element's center on canvas center. Please help and if you can suggest any better ways to place things on canvas center by attached properties then please tell me how to implement it. Please help.

Comment: Why should you be able to drag and drop stuff around --- your code does not contain anything related to drag and drop! Maybe a short clarification is in order: People here will gladly help you (a) find bugs in your code, (b) get you on the right track to solve a problem and (c) help you understand WPF concepts. What you probably *won't* get is: "I need a program which does X, please write it for me."

Comment: OK, to get back to your problem: Why do you use a Panel instead of a Canvas as the base class? The dragging example you linked in your question needs the Left, Top etc. attached properties of `Canvas`, which probably have some code attached to them (so you cannot create the same effect by using a Panel and re-creating these attached properties).

Comment: No no getting the code written was not my intention, I'm sorry if I've put it that way. But the thing is If use the drag concept and the centering conept on the same canvas class everything is getting messed up. I'm not able to do either. Can you suggest any good ways to put elements on canvas center with attached properties. What I need is a guide to not the program. Please don't misunderstand me.