# WPF Canvas: centered origin, scaled axes (and y inverted), responding to mouse events

Tags: wpf, canvas, mouseevent

In a simple code-only WPF application I'm writing, I would like to have a custom `Canvas`.

I've found questions similar to this one here in StackOverflow, but couldn't find exactly this one, nor a simple way to adapt another answer to my specific problem (please note that I have not much experience in WPF).

In my canvas, I'd like it to have the following properties:

1. the point (0, 0) is on the center of the `Canvas`;
2. the x-axis points to the right;
3. the y-axis points to the top;
4. the point (1, 0) is about 1 inch to the right of the origin; and
5. in every event, the position of the mouse is given in the coordinate system defined above.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871358/wpf-how-to-make-the-0-0-in-center-inside-a-canvas/1965257#1965257), Ray Burns propose a very simple solution to my first 3 points. It is trivial to modify that code so that it deals with my point number 4 as well (change `1` and `-1` in the `RenderTransform` to other constants).

However, that very simple and excellent solution for many problems is based on setting width and height to 0, and centering the canvas on its container. Therefore, **there's no canvas** to capture events like a click, so this solution won't handle my fifth property.

What's the easiest way to achieve this? Inherit from `Panel` and do everything by hand? Inherit from `Canvas`, intercept every event and modify the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Put `Canvas` inside a `Border`. `Border` has mouse events. Another case is to place `Border` on the top of the `Canvas`.