# Scaling in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I changed my WPF canvas origin to center of the screen using the below xaml code.

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
        <TranslateTransform
            X="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"
            Y="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"/>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

I used scale transform in above xaml code to achieve that. But now, I was unable to apply scale transform any more on my canvas to resize the contents of canvas (lines and polygons).

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing a bit of information here, most importantly: What are you trying to do? What is the expected outcome? You can read more details here: [mcve]

Comment: Probably related: [WPF: how to make the (0,0) in center inside a Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871358/wpf-how-to-make-the-0-0-in-center-inside-a-canvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler way to "center" the coordinate system origin of a Canvas would be to put it in the bottom-right cell of a 2x2 Grid. Since the default value of the Canvas' `ClipToBounds` property is `false`, elements at negative coordinates are still visible.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        ...
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```