# How does LineSegment work in wpf

Tags: wpf

```
      <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
          <LineSegment Point="0,100"></LineSegment>
          <LineSegment Point="100,100"></LineSegment>
    </PathFigure>
```

I dont understand how does the above xaml output display?
Can anyone explain what happens for the above code?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? There is also [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.linesegment.aspx).

Comment: I have tried it but I dont understand how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it is like drawing on a graph paper

- Put your pen down on point 0,0
- move from 0,0 to 0,100
- move from 0,100 to 100, 100

The only thing to note is that in WPF the y axis is inverted, so you get something like this:

[image]

- The red line is your first move
- The blue line is your second move

Comment: The polygon that u just mentioned is not the exact output.

Comment: @sly_Chandan I updated the answer. You are probably talking about the y-axis being inverted as to why you see it wrong

Comment: Perfect buddy.Now I get the proper output. My Question is why is the y axis inverted?

Comment: I believe this is legacy from winforms treating grids with 0,0 in the top left, but am not certain....talk to Microsoft :p. If you want, you can invert it back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185948/how-to-change-x-y-origin-of-canvas-to-bottom-left-and-flip-the-y-coordinates