# How to resize a rectangle from the bottom up? XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

The figure below shows me changing two values ​​for height. When I decrease the height instead of the figure decreasing from top to bottom the opposite happens.

[image]

[image]

```
<Rectangle Fill="#DBDBDB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="547,607,0,0" Stroke="Silver" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.97" />
```

I just need to know how to set X and Y

Comment: Simply subtract the delta from the top.

Comment: Does [this question help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185948/how-to-change-x-y-origin-of-canvas-to-bottom-left-and-flip-the-y-coordinates)?

Comment: Is the Rectangle on a Canvas? Or in a Grid? Or other?

Comment: After re-reading, it seems to me (I can be wrong of course) that you think that Y-axis is directed from bottom to top. However, it is vice versa. So to say the "origin" of a rectangle is its up left corner, not the bottom left one.

Comment: @AlexD I would like to change that! I want to set the origin on the left side in parde low. Is it possible?

Comment: @RonaldAraújo Try `<ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348048.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rectangle happens to be on a Canvas, you can make use of the Canvas.Right and Canvas.Bottom

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Shrink It a Bit</Button>
    <Rectangle x:Name="_Rectangle" Canvas.Bottom="20" Canvas.Right="20" 
               Fill="Black" Height="50" Width="50" />
</Canvas>
```

So now if you shrink it:

```
_Rectangle.Height = _Rectangle.Height - 5;
_Rectangle.Width = _Rectangle.Width - 5;
```

you'll notice that it shrinks from the top and left. You can use the appropriate combinations of Top/Bottom, Right/Left to get the effect you desire.

Comment: Please. Look at my question again. Updated figures.